# Using jQuery autocomplete from PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My database columns as shown below:

```sql
  `matDes1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matCost1` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matDes2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matCost2` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matDes3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matCost3` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matDes4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matCost4` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matDes5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `matCost5` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
```

I have a dynamic table with add and remove rows inside my HTML file.

Inside this table I have textarea and input, whenever I start typing will show me suggestions, and if I select one, will automatically populate other fields.

Here below my textarea and input:

```html
<textarea id='codeANCILLARY_1' class='codeANCILLARY' name="codeANCILLARY[]"></textarea>

<input type="text" id="mat50ANCILLARY_1" class="mat50ANCILLARY" name="mat50ANCILLARY[]" />
```

textarea Searching through matDes1 to matDes5. so no problem here.

the problem is when selecting to populate both field, only accepting matDes1 and matCost1 not the rest.

is there a way to use say something like if statement and say:

```js
if (matDes1 selected) {
show matDes1 with matCost1
} else if (matDes2 selected){
show matDes2 with matCost2
}
and 
so 
on
```

i really dont know anymore  what must i do. :(

The full jQuery and PHP files are:

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '.codeANCILLARY', function () {

        var id = this.id;
        var splitid = id.split('_');
        var count = splitid[1];

        $('#' + id).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../MY_PHP_PAGE",
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        search: request.term,
                        request: 1
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                var id = ui.item.value;

                // AJAX
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../../MY_PHP_PAGE',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        request: 2
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (takesAnyVaribale) {
                        var len = takesAnyVaribale.length;
                        if (len > 0) {
                            var codeANCILLARY = takesAnyVaribale[0]['codeANCILLARY'];
                            var mat50ANCILLARY = takesAnyVaribale[0]['mat50ANCILLARY'];
                            var unitsANCILLARY = takesAnyVaribale[0]['unitsANCILLARY'];
                          
                            $('#codeANCILLARY_' + count).val(codeANCILLARY);
                            $('#mat50ANCILLARY_' + count).val(mat50ANCILLARY);
                            $('#unitsANCILLARY_' + count).val(unitsANCILLARY);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
"MY_PHP_PAGE"

include "config.php";
$request = $_POST['request'];

if ($request == 1) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST WHERE matDes1 like'%".$search."%'";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST WHERE matDes2 like'%".$search."%'";
    $query3 = "SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST WHERE matDes3 like'%".$search."%'";
    $query4 = "SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST WHERE matDes4 like'%".$search."%'";
    $query5 = "SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST WHERE matDes5 like'%".$search."%'";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query1);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $query3);
    $result4 = mysqli_query($con, $query4);
    $result5 = mysqli_query($con, $query5);
    if ($result1 || $result2 || $result3 || $result4 || $result5) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['matDes1']);
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['matDes2']);
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['matDes3']);
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['matDes4']);
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)) {
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row['id'],"label"=>$row['matDes5']);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

if ($request == 2) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST WHERE id=".$id;
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $AncillaryPricing_arr = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $codeANCILLARY = $row['matDes1'];
        $mat50ANCILLARY = $row['matCost1'];
        //***************************
        //***************************
        $codeANCILLARY = $row['matDes2'];        
         $mat50ANCILLARY = $row['matCost2'];
        .and
        .so on 
        .until 5
        //***************************
        //***************************
        $unitsANCILLARY = $row['units'];
        $AncillaryPricing_arr[] = array(
            "id" => $id,
            "codeANCILLARY" => $codeANCILLARY,
            "mat50ANCILLARY" => $mat50ANCILLARY,
            "unitsANCILLARY" => $unitsANCILLARY
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($AncillaryPricing_arr);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you just want to retrieve either by ID _or_ by searching in those columns, or that you want to retrieve all those columns and pass them back, as you do with the four columns you already return? If the latter, isn't it just a case of adding them all to the array?

Comment: bear in mind that select value out of these 10 columns goes inside one input field only one and not array of all

Comment: if you look at jQuery  $('#codeANCILLARY_' + count).val(codeANCILLARY);

Answer (score 0):

You really need a better database layout for exactly this reason. Split the `matdes` and `matcost` columns out into a separate table, linked by the component ID. You can have as many as you want, then, and it's much easier to search them. Instead of all your separate queries, you'd have something like

```
SELECT * FROM MY_COMPONENTLIST_MAT WHERE matDes like'%".$search."%' and component_id = " . $id
```

(except as a prepared statement) and it would find any of them. You can use a JOIN to get the rest of the information from the main component list.

Comment: i can search through them but i can not select them

Comment: i wish if i could have one of you next to me and explain better

Comment: is it anyway that i could speak with you via WhatsApp, or teamviewer . i know im asking too much but im really stuck please helppppp!!!!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have either of those things.

Comment: i know that i could change my database table into two table then join them by say an id but this table feeding my quote system and invoice system and also my PO system

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure I'm actually helping with the problem you have, just thinking it might be easier with a different layout, if that's something you can do.

Comment: it is very time consuming

Comment: i tried extending if request == 3 and    if request == 4 and so on and inside each replace matDes1 and matCost1 to  matDes2 and matCost2 and 3 but thats not working too

Comment: i can easily concatenating them say $codeANCILLARY = $row['matDes1'] ." ".$row['matDes2']." ".$row['matDes3']; and so on but i dont want that my input field will be unreadable